# std::condition_variable thread contention

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, condition-variable

I have an issue where my condition_variables do not seem to be notifying each other.
From what I have read it seems the main reason the `condition_variable` does not work correctly is because the lock was only being used in the 'wait' thread. That said my code below uses the mutex in both the wait and notify threads but still does not run correctly.

Is there something I am missing?

Thanks.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

std::condition_variable cv_one;
std::condition_variable cv_two;

std::mutex m_one;
std::mutex m_two;

void one(  )
{
  std::unique_lock< std::mutex > lock { m_one };
  cv_one.notify_one( );

  std::cout << "one" << std::endl;
}

void two(  )
{
  {
    std::unique_lock< std::mutex > lock { m_one };
    cv_one.wait( lock );

    std::cout << "two" << std::endl;
  }

  {
    std::unique_lock< std::mutex > lock { m_two };
    cv_two.notify_one(  );
  }
}

void three( )
{
  std::unique_lock< std::mutex > lock { m_two };
  cv_two.wait( lock );

  std::cout << "three" << std::endl;
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  std::thread thread_one( one );
  std::thread thread_two( two );
  std::thread thread_three( three );

  std::cin.get(  );

  cv_one.notify_all( );

  thread_three.join( );
  thread_two.join( );
  thread_one.join( );

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might be confusing a condition variable with a semaphore...

Comment: Define "does not run correctly". What outcome do you expect, and what do you observe? Note that it's possible for `one()` to call `notify_one` before `two()` reaches `wait`, in which case `notify_one` is a no-op.

Comment: absolutely, a condition variable DOES NOT store the notify flag, it must be used to check a CONDITION. and one MUST loop over this condition check on top of that. And obviously you cannot notify cross-mutex.

Answer (score 0):

The condition variables are not notifying each other because you are notifying at the wrong times.  For example, if `one` calls `cv_one.notify()` *before* `two` calls `cv_one.wait(lock)`, then `two` will block forever. As far as `two` sees, no thread ever notified it *while it was waiting*.  This is what @v.oddou meant, that the notify flag is not stored.

The `std::cin` line acted as a delay, which is why the output is correct with that there.  All of the threads get to the place where they are waiting on the condition variables in the delay it takes you to press the button.

You can see the problem happening when in this code example, which shows when threads start waiting along when they are woken up.  I switched to single characters so that the output isn't a garbled mess.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

std::condition_variable cv_one;
std::condition_variable cv_two;

std::mutex m_one;
std::mutex m_two;

void one()
{
    std::unique_lock< std::mutex > lock { m_one };
    std::cout << "x" << std::endl;
    cv_one.notify_one();

    std::cout << "a" << std::endl;
}

void two()
{
    {
        std::unique_lock< std::mutex > lock { m_one };
        std::cout << "y" << std::endl;
        cv_one.wait( lock );

        std::cout << "b" << std::endl;
    }

    {
        std::unique_lock< std::mutex > lock { m_two };
        cv_two.notify_one();
    }
}

void three()
{
    std::unique_lock< std::mutex > lock { m_two };
    std::cout << "z" << std::endl;
    cv_two.wait( lock );

    std::cout << "c" << std::endl;
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    std::thread thread_one(one);
    std::thread thread_two(two);
    std::thread thread_three(three);

    std::cout << "d" << std::endl;
    cv_one.notify_all();

    thread_three.join();
    thread_two.join();
    thread_one.join();

    return 0;
}
```